# How do I convert an unsigned long array to byte in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I convert an unsigned long array to byte in C++? I'm developing using VS2008 C++.

Edit:

I need to evaluate the size of this converted number,I want to divide this long array to a 29byte array. 
for example we have  long array = 12345;
it should convert to byte and then I need its length to divide to 29 and see how many packet is it.

losing data is important but right now I just want to get result.

Comment: Please explain further.  Do you need to copy it, or is it sufficient to access the original array using a `char *`?  Do you need to change the endianness?

Comment: Surely there's a reason that it is `long`? You risk losing data. Can you explain more about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Like Matthew said: What are we doing here? A we doing some sort of down-sampling? Are we serializing to a byte stream for output on a network/file/etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
long array[SOME_SIZE];
char* ptr = reinterpret_cast<char*>( array ); // or just ( char* )array; in C

// PC is little-endian platform
for ( size_t i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE*sizeof( long ); i++ )
{
    printf( "%x", ptr[i] );
}
```

Here's more robust solution for you, no endianness (this does not cover weird DSP devices where `char` can be 32-bit entity, those are special):

```
long array[SOME_SIZE];

for ( size_t i = 0; i < SOME_SIZE; i++ )
{
    for ( size_t j = 0; j < sizeof( long ); j++ )
    {
        // my characters are 8 bit
        printf( "%x", (( array[i] >> ( j << 3 )) & 0xff ));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the data in ptr will only be little-endian on little-endian machines: This solution will result in big-endian output on big-endian machines, and little-endian output on little endian machines. Understand what endian-ness means, and if endian-ness matters, seek a more robust solution.

Comment: Thanks for your solution,I hope it work,but would u help me,how I can count how many byte is it? in other hand for example 10 equal 1001 so it is 4 byte

Comment: You can deal with freaky sizes of `char` by replacing `j << 3` with `j * CHAR_BIT`, and `0xff` with `((1 << CHAR_BIT) - 1)`. You'll need to include `<climits>` for that.

Comment: @rima, I think we are still lost at what you need to do. Is it a single `long` number or an array of `long`s? Can you include at least some snippet of code in the question of what you think you should be doing?

Comment: I try to change some codes,emmm it's hard for me to put codes here,It was code of one of the WSN security algorithm (ECC)...

Comment: Prefer `j * 8` over `j << 3` - the former is much clearer, and is what you are actually doing. Leave the micro-optimization to the compiler.